# how to display each row from database in different page in php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have a code that display 3 questions and multiple answers from database for user to select. after choosing the answers  user will hit the submit button. its works fine.

**Current Code:**

```
<?php

$today=date("Y-m-d");

echo "<form method='post' id='submit' action='checkresult.php' dir='rtl'>";
$sql="SELECT * FROM cquestions where showdate='$today' limit 3";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<p>" . $row['cqtext'] . "</p>";
   $sql2="SELECT * FROM canswers where cqid=".$row['cqid'];
   $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
   while($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
   {
      echo "<input type='radio' name='".$row['cqid']."' value='".$row2['cqans']."' />".$row2['aatext']; 
   }
}


$tomorrow= date("Y-m-d", strtotime("tomorrow"));
$sql4="SELECT * FROM qupdate";
$result4=mysql_query($sql4);
$last_update=mysql_result($result4,"last_update");
if($last_update==$today)
{
    $cqid=mysql_result($result,"cqid");
    $update1="update cquestions set showdate='$tomorrow' where showdate='0000-00-00' and cqid!='$cqid' order by cqid limit 3";
    mysql_query($update1);
    $update2="update qupdate set last_update='$tomorrow'";
    mysql_query($update2);
    $sql3="SELECT * FROM qupdate";
    $result3=mysql_query($sql3);
    $last_update=mysql_result($result3,"last_update");  
}

echo"<br>";
echo"<br>";
echo"<input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='Submit Answers' />";
echo "</form>" ;
?>
```

**Output of above code**

```
question1
ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4

question2
ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4

question3
ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4

SUBMIT
```

i want make some changes. i want  to make it to display 1st question in first page, and user clicks next then it must go to 2nd question, then 3rd question and finally submit button.

**Expecting Output**

```
page1
Question 1
ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4

Next

after choosing the ans user clicks next
page2
question 2
ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4

Next

page3
question 3
ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4

SUBMIT Button.
```

how to do it?

Comment: hi DevZer0! paging..?! i am new to php. could you help me? how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `jquery show/hide or fadeIn/fadeOut` like

```
<form>
<div id="question1" class="questions">
//php question and its answers in radio
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getnext('question2')"></a>
</div>
<div id="question2" class="questions" style="display:none">
//php question and its answers in radio
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getnext('question3')"></a>
</div>
<div id="question3" class="questions" style="display:none">
//php question and its answers in radio
<input type="submit"/>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function getnext(id){
//for fade effect
$(".questions").fadeOut("fast");
$("#"+id).fadeIn("slow");
//for show/hide
$(".questions").hide();
$("#"+id).show();
 }
 </script>
```

Make sure you have included `jquery`

Answer (score 0):

**In HTML**

at end of page one:

```
<a href="?gotopage=2">Next</a>
```

And

at end of page two:

```
<a href="?gotopage=3">Next</a>
```

And

at end of page three:

```
<a href="?dosubmit">Submit</a>
```

**In PHP**

```
if( isset($_GET['gotopage'])  && $_GET['gotopage'] == 2 ){
   //codes for 2 page
}
```

And so on...

Comment: hi EmRa228? how to alter my current code? now i am displaying 3 rows of data. so now i want to display single row in each page? for example , for second page i have to display only the second row from table?

Answer (score 0):

Paging is a simple concept where each record is written to a  that shows as a page, and has links that traverse toward other pages that has other record data ..

**Reference:** [Simple and easy PHP pagination](http://snipplr.com/view/55519/)